# Error when trying to remove a gwidget using delete

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have a problem when trying to use the delete method in gWidgets

```
require('gWidgets')
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
win <- gWidgets::gwindow("trial", name="main",parent=c(0,0),width=400,height=100)
group<- gWidgets::ggroup(horizontal=TRUE) 
gWidgets::add(win,group,expand=FALSE)
frame<-gframe("frame to remove")
add(group,frame)
delete(group,frame)
```

This code returns the following error.

```
Error in unclass(x) : cannot unclass an external pointer
```

gWidgets: Version: 0.0-54, RGtk2 :Version: 2.20.33, R win64

This problem is new in 2.4.0, could anyone give me a tip on how to solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. I re-installed RGtk2 :Version: 2.20.31 and everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for following up with this detail.